# How can I import matterjs as an npm module into my p5 sketch?

Tags: javascript, node.js, p5.js, matter.js

I am developing a P5 sketch, that I started by following Daniel Shiffman's "Using Express with Node - WebSockets and p5.js Tutorial" (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2hhEOGXcCvg). I would like to utilize Matter.js physics, so I installed matterjs with npm (`npm install matterjs`). I would like to import the `./node_modules/matterjs/dist/matter.js` file in my p5.js sketch, but I can't figure out the right way to do it.

Here's what my file structure looks like:

```
./server.js
./public/
   index.html
   sketch.js
./node_modules/
   matterjs/
      dist/
         matter.js
```

So far, I've tried the following:

**1**. Treating the `matter.js` like a regular JS file and adding the relative path to it in `index.html`:

```
    ...
    <body>
      <script src="../node_modules/matterjs/dist/matter.js"></script>
      ...
```

In `sketch.js` I then attempted to use the `Matter` class
`var Engine = Matter.Engine;`
But this gave me an "UnCaught ReferenceError: Matter is not defined"

**2**. Again, including the relative path in `index.html`, but this time in `sketch.js`, I attempted to import `matter.js`:
`import Matter from "matter";`

This gave me an "Unexpected identifier" error on the import line. Chrome put a red squiggly line under `Matter from "matter";`

**3**. Removing the reference to the `matter.js` file in `index.html`, and adding the relative path to the import line in `sketch.js`:
`import Matter from ""../node_modules/matterjs/dist/matter";`

This gave me two errors:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/node_modules/matterjs/dist/matter.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)     localhost:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

For reference, here's what some of my files look like:

**server.js**

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()

// get the port number from the command line args
const port = (process.argv.length > 2) ? process.argv[2] : 3000

console.log("Starting server on port " + port)

var server = app.listen(port)
app.use(express.static('public'))
```

**sketch.js**

```
/*jshint esversion: 8 */

import Matter from "matter"; // this changed as I was trying different things

// matter.js
var Engine = Matter.Engine;
...
```

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>
  <!-- root path to p5.js CDN: https://cdnjs.com/libraries/p5.js -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.9.0/p5.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.9.0/addons/p5.dom.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.9.0/addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
  <script src="../node_modules/matterjs/dist/matter.js"></script> // this changed as I was trying different things
</body></html>
```

I know that I could add a reference to a `matter.js` file hosted on the web, but I would like to avoid having to manage two different matter instances in the same project.

Comment: There seems to be some confusion about what's on the server and what's on the client. Are you looking to run matter.js on the server or in the client's browser? It seems like you have p5 running on the client and you want MJS to run on the client too, in which case you can include it from a CDN as you'd do without any backend/server code. If you want MJS on the server, see [Running Matter.js on a Node server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61164289/running-matter-js-on-a-node-server/62687244#62687244) which can be adapted to p5.js instead of canvas on the client easily.

Answer (score 0):

When you `npm i` a package, it saves the files to the local /node_modules/ folder so it can be used locally by node.js scripts. You are trying to use a local, serverside file with your client, which will not work.

A couple of solutions are:

- (easy fix) use matter.js from a cdn like you have been doing from p5.js (https://cdnjs.com/libraries/matter-js)
- An alternate way is to use something like [webpack](https://webpack.js.org) to bundle all of your assets together, and then host that.